# Hide Banner Space when there there are no Ads Android

Tags: android, view, ads

I recently changed from Admob SDK to GPS Lib and there is 1 thing bothering me.
I have a simple View to define line in my Layout to prevent users from clicking on ads unintentionally. With Admob SDK that line would drop to the bottom of layout when there are no ads, but with GPS Lib, that View remains where it is. 
[image]

And when there are no ads, when user is using app in offline mode there is that empty ugly space. 
[image]

How can I get rid of that space when there are no ads?
Here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back2" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upperBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#000000" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bar"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/infop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/info_select_blue" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/share_selector_blue" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moreaps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/more_selector_blue" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbsz"
        android:columnWidth="110dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="12dp" >
    </GridView>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbsz"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upperBar"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark"
        android:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to check programatically there are ad present or no.if ads are not present then just set

```
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

else

```
adView.setVisibility(View.Visible)
```

thats it...

Comment: Oh yeah. I was thinking of checking if device is connected to internet or not and then make something with Boolean but this is better. Thanks

Comment: This will cause issues. If you have internet but the first ad fails to load due to fill and any reason, your ads will never refresh nor display again later because the view is hidden and admob will say 'Ad not visible, not refreshing'. Another scenario, the internet is off, so the adview is hidden, then they turn the internet on, you can either leave it and no ad will ever display, or show the adview area again which will exhibit the original problem if it still fails for other reasons

Answer (score 18):

Hide your adView initially by adding android:visibility="gone"

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Now handle adview visibility in setAdListener

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }    

});
```

This will result in exact same behavior as the old Admob SDK.

Comment: The problem with this is that if Ad load failed once, the banner will disappear and therefore there won't be ad refresh as well. AdMob doesn't refresh ad if the ad view is not visible.

Comment: @user846316, Just call adView load ad function from your code intelligently.

Comment: Except the ad won't ever load if it failed the first time but would have been ok the second/future refreshes